# What is the API endpoint in apache superset to update the filter values in an embedded chart?

Tags: apache-superset

I want to use custom react filter components on my embedded Apache superset dashboard. I was able to embed a dashboard using the superset-ui/embedded-sdk but I'm unable to pass filter values through the sdk that dynamically update the dashboard. So I want to send a POST request with my filter values to the API endpoint that updates the filter values of the queries in my dashboard. I also didn't want to use URL parameters as updating a single parameter meant for one chart updates the entire dashboard.

I've tried looking at the URL's POST requests made when I used a filter box in an embedded dashboard, and tried sending filter values to the same URL's but the charts in my dashboard don't reload. I am able to get the data for the chart but the chart inside the dashboard doesn't reload. I also made sure that the request bodies that I have sent are the same as the ones that were made when I used the filter box. I'm not sure if the endpoint is supposed to only fetch the data in which case I'm looking at how to update the chart with the data that I have fetched.

Superset version - 2.0.1

This was the endpoint that I tried;
http://localhost:8088/api/v1/chart/data

Comment: Any one have a solution?